# How to delete lines in xml using logstash

Tags: logstash

everybody.
I am new to logstash. I've been studying filters in logstash for a week, but no result.
I want to parse xml. I have the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<ContinentLogs>
    <Cryptogateways>
        <cgw id="1" cssid="0" ip="0.0.0.0" tz="RCPTZ -3:00 RCPTZS -4:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00">ЦУС</cgw>
        <cgw id="2" cssid="50556" ip="0.0.0.0" tz="RCPTZ -3:00 RCPTZS -4:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00">DP.152FZ.DA01</cgw>
        <cgw id="3" cssid="50557" ip="0.0.0.0" tz="RCPTZ -3:00 RCPTZS -4:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00">M1.152FZ.DA01</cgw>
        <cgw id="4" cssid="51358" ip="0.0.0.0" tz="RCPTZ 00:00 RCPTZS 00:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00">3D Get</cgw>
        <cgw id="5" cssid="51491" ip="0.0.0.0" tz="RCPTZ -3:00 RCPTZS -4:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00">М1.152FZ.CUS02</cgw>
        <cgw id="6" cssid="51845" ip="0.0.0.0" tz="RCPTZ -3:00 RCPTZS -4:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00">DP.152FZ.FW01</cgw>
        <cgw id="7" cssid="51847" ip="0.0.0.0" tz="RCPTZ -3:00 RCPTZS -4:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00">M1.152FZ.FW01</cgw>
        <cgw id="8" cssid="53840" ip="0.0.0.0" tz="RCPTZ -3:00 RCPTZS -4:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00">M1.152FZ.FW02</cgw>
        <cgw id="9" cssid="68604" ip="0.0.0.0" tz="RCPTZ -3:00 RCPTZS -4:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00">TNC MIG</cgw>
        <cgw id="10" cssid="69007" ip="0.0.0.0" tz="RCPTZ -3:00 RCPTZS -4:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00">HAKR</cgw>
        <cgw id="11" cssid="111846" ip="0.0.0.0" tz="RCPTZ -3:00 RCPTZS -4:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00">ALT MOT</cgw>
        <cgw id="12" cssid="111978" ip="0.0.0.0" tz="RCPTZ -3:00 RCPTZS -4:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00,M0.0.0/00:00:00">GPB RIM</cgw>
    </Cryptogateways>
    <FilterRules>
        <rule id="-8" deleted="false">Pravil</rule>
        <rule id="-5" deleted="false">(?) Neopredelen</rule>
        <rule id="-3" deleted="false">Udalenni pravila</rule>
        <rule id="-2" deleted="false">SD prav</rule>
        <rule id="-1" deleted="false">Slygeb prav</rule>
        <rule id="0" deleted="false">Ne sootvetsvyet</rule>
        <rule id="17" deleted="false">Mon =&gt; Mail Server</rule>
    </FilterRules>
</ContinentLogs>
```

I want to remove lines that have «cgw id="3"» и «cgw id="7"» in the  section.
And remove the lines that have «rule id="-5"» и «rule id="0"» in the  section.
Write everything back to xml without changing anything else.
Help how to do this through Logstash?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Logstash is not feeding the ELK. I just want to convert xml.

Answer (score 0):

if your logstash is feeding the ELK, then your solution should be in [Prune](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-prune.html) blacklist
first, add the item you want in the xpath
for example
let my Xml file be like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
   <Appenders>
      <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
         <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
      </Console>
   </Appenders>
   <Loggers>
      <Logger name="com.foo.Bar" level="trace">
         <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
      </Logger>
       <Logger name="com.foo.Bar.test.2.error" level="error">
         <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
      </Logger>
      <Root level="error">
         <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
      </Root>
   </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

and now in the configuration file use the filter as the following.

```
filter {
    
       xml {
            source => "message"
            store_xml => false
            target => "rec"
            xpath => [
                    "/Configuration /@status", "Configuration_LEVEL" // defining my item to delete
            ]
        }
       prune {
        blacklist_names => ["Configuration_LEVEL"] // delete the item using prune blacklist
      }
    }
```

I hope it helped you.

Comment: for more info about mapping the XPath in your XML file, use the following tool [Code Beautify][1]


  [1]: https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester